# Alternative grids with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I'd like a responsive grid system that would concatenate my titles to all rows with the smallest mediaquery. I know that there are some solutions out of bootstrap like those on this page http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns.

Do someone know a plugin or method that would allow such feature with bootstrap ? I already checked http://startbootstrap.com/bootstrap-resources/ but found nothing like that. An alternative method that would be acceptable would be to fix the table headers at some point so that they're always visible to the user browsing the table even if he scrolls down the full page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this! i don´t know if this is what you exactly mean:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
            /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
            
            #no-more-tables table,
            #no-more-tables thead,
            #no-more-tables tbody,
            #no-more-tables th,
            #no-more-tables td,
            #no-more-tables tr {
                display: block;
            }
            /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
            
            #no-more-tables thead tr {
                position: absolute;
                top: -9999px;
                left: -9999px;
            }
            #no-more-tables tr {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
            #no-more-tables td {
                /* Behave  like a "row" */
                
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                position: relative;
                padding-left: 50%;
                white-space: normal;
                text-align: left;
            }
            #no-more-tables td:before {
                /* Now like a table header */
                
                position: absolute;
                /* Top/left values mimic padding */
                
                top: 6px;
                left: 6px;
                width: 45%;
                padding-right: 10px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                text-align: left;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            /*
 Label the data
 */
            
            #no-more-tables td:before {
                content: attr(data-title);
            }
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Getting Started With Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="no-more-tables">
                <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th class="number">Price</th>
                            <th class="number">Change</th>
                            <th class="number">Change %</th>
                            <th class="number">Open</th>
                            <th class="number">High</th>
                            <th class="number">Low</th>
                            <th class="number">Volume</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$1.38</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">-0.01</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">-0.36%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$1.39</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$1.39</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$1.38</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">9,395</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">AAD</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">ARDENT LEISURE GROUP</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$1.15</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">+0.02</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">1.32%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$1.14</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$1.15</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$1.13</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">56,431</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">AAX</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">AUSENCO LIMITED</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$4.00</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">-0.04</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">-0.99%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$4.01</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$4.05</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$4.00</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">90,641</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">ABC</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">ADELAIDE BRIGHTON LIMITED</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$3.00</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">+0.06</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">2.04%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$2.98</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$3.00</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$2.96</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">862,518</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">ABP</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">ABACUS PROPERTY GROUP</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$1.91</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">0.00</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">0.00%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$1.92</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$1.93</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$1.90</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">595,701</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">ABY</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">ADITYA BIRLA MINERALS LIMITED</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$0.77</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">+0.02</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">2.00%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$0.76</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$0.77</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$0.76</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">54,567</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">ACR</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">ACRUX LIMITED</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$3.71</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">+0.01</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">0.14%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$3.70</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$3.72</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$3.68</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">191,373</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">ADU</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">ADAMUS RESOURCES LIMITED</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$0.72</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">0.00</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">0.00%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$0.73</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$0.74</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$0.72</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">8,602,291</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">AGG</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">ANGLOGOLD ASHANTI LIMITED</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$7.81</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">-0.22</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">-2.74%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$7.82</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$7.82</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$7.81</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">148</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">AGK</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">AGL ENERGY LIMITED</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$13.82</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">+0.02</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">0.14%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$13.83</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$13.83</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$13.67</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">846,403</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Code">AGO</td>
                            <td data-title="Company">ATLAS IRON LIMITED</td>
                            <td data-title="Price" class="number">$3.17</td>
                            <td data-title="Change" class="number">-0.02</td>
                            <td data-title="Change %" class="number">-0.47%</td>
                            <td data-title="Open" class="number">$3.11</td>
                            <td data-title="High" class="number">$3.22</td>
                            <td data-title="Low" class="number">$3.10</td>
                            <td data-title="Volume" class="number">5,416,303</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I was searching for.